# How to eliminate prompt when adding new value to dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, overwrite

Question is worded weirdly. It's hard to word it in a few words. But here we go: 
I have written this program that prompts a user for their name and some data associated with them. If you enter the same name a second time, the program will ask you if you want to update in which case, you type `y` (for yes) and you can enter the new data to be stored. When you hit `enter` or `return` twice, the program will list the keys and their values.

Here is the code:

```
def thing():

    store = {}

    while True:
        name = input('Perp: ')
        if not name:
            for k, v in store.items():
                print('Perp' + k + ' has a ' + v)
            break

        if name in store:

            if input(name + ' has ' + store[name] + '. Update? ') != 'y':
                continue

        store[name] = input('item: ')
```

Now, what I want to do is eliminate the whole prompt I give in this code 
`if input(name + ' has ' + store[name] + '. Update? ') != 'y':`. I just want when I enter the name a second time, it will show me `Item:` and I enter the item and when I hit `enter` twice and it lists the keys and the values, it will show me the updated pair.

I just want to eliminate the prompt of asking the user whether they want to update or not. If they enter the name in a second time, we will assume that is the intention.

I've tried messing with this line of code a lot where I tried 
`if input('Item: ')!= ''`, but that failed. And a bunch of other variations of the code. Then I realized I need to eliminate this `input`, in a way. When I deleted that line, obviously the code didn't work as it should. I know for a fact this is a tiny fix but I have been staring at it for hours and I can't get it.

An output would be like this:

`Perp: Batman`
`Item: Batarang` 
`Perp: Superman` 
`Item: Heat Vision` 
`Perp: Syndrome` 
`Item: Stupidity` 
`Perp: Batman` 
`Item: Kryptonite`
`Perp:`
`Batman has Kryptonite`
`Superman has Heat Vision`
`Syndrome has Stupidity`

PS, sorry if my superhero examples upset you.

Here is my code exactly.

[image]

Comment: so... removing the `if input(name + ' has ' + store[name] + '. Update? ') != 'y':  continue` did not do what you wanted?

Comment: Correct. If I remove up to and including `continue`, it will never prompt me for the item. Now, if I remove up to but not including `continue`, so simply `if input(name + ' has ' + store[name] + '. Update? ') != 'y':`, it will return both items for batman `batarang` and `kryptonite` when it should only return the last one.

Comment: Also, when I do delete that line, again not including `continue`, I will indent the last line `store[name] = input('item: ')` to be directly under `continue`.

Comment: the way it is written removing the conditional and the `continue` would result in a `SyntaxError` because then the block `if name in store:` is empty, if you left the `continue` it would then become the only thing in the condition `if name in store:` so if the name was already present it would skip asking for a new item, something does not match up with what you are describing and the code you have posted, are you sure this is the exact code?

Comment: having something directly under a continue is pointless as it would never be reached.

Comment: When I indent the last line `store[name] = input('item: ')` it would be directly under the if statement and right before continue. I mistyped it the first time. But yes, exactly as I have it here.
Right, let me see if I can post a picture of it.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, see updated post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113970/discussion-between-tadhg-mcdonald-jensen-and-adhamncheese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just skip the `if name in store:` check and just ask for the item again when name is not blank:

```
def thing():

    store = {}

    while True:
        name = input('Perp: ')
        if not name:
            for k, v in store.items():
                print('Perp' + k + ' has a ' + v)
            break
        else:    
            store[name] = input('item: ')
```